# OPC Publisher and message routing

Tags: azure-iot-edge, azure-industrial-iot

Message routing on IoT Edge is great to parse/filter messages before sending them to Azure.
What would be the output path for message routing of data from publisher to $upstream (and later another module).

```
/messages/* is not working
/messages/modules/* is not working
/messages/devices/* is not working
```

The IoT Hub contains the Edge device and IoT devices for each machine connected by the publisher. <- is this the normal setup?

Deployed is the image with tag 2.8.45 (if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 1):

It is depending whether the OPC Publisher is working in standalone mode or orchestrated mode. Your description is accurate for the orchestrated mode. In standalone mode the OPC Publisher using it's own Edge Module identity to send data of all connected OPC UA Server to IoT Hub.

The routing for transparent gateway mode is done via

```
FROM /messages/* WHERE NOT IS_DEFINED($connectionModuleId) INTO $upstream
```

You can add another route with the same from and [BrokeredEndpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-composition?view=iotedge-2018-06#sink) if you whish to send the messages also into your own edge module.

*Hint: Version 2.8.X of Industrial IoT Platform is currently under development, for production use cases, please use the latest release **2.7.199**.*

Answer (score 0):

The publisher module uses for telemetry a different IoT device for every endpoint connected, in the so called transparent gateway mode for the edge device. The reason of using transparent gateway mode is to ensure distribution of the telemetry data coming from an edge device in the different partitions at the IoT Hub level for scalability reasons.
We have recently updated the default message routing to reflect better this mode of operation.